# Assigning a sparse matrix in Eigen

Tags: linear-algebra, eigen

I read through this [page](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialSparse.html) on assigning a sparse matrix. Unfortunately, I do not understand it. Can anyone help me out with an example? For instance, how should I assign the following 10 by 8 sparse matrix in Eigen?

A(1,2) = 3; A(1,4) = 10; A(2,1) = 9; A(2,8) = 9; A(4,7) = 11; A(5,3) = -23; A(7,6) = 21; A(9,3) = 45; A(10,7) = 76;

Answer (score 6):

First of all, for matrices smaller than about 500x(00 there is no clear advantage of using a sparse representation. So for 10x8 you should really simply use a dense MatrixXf. Nonetheless, to fill a sparse matrix the recommended way is to fill an intermediate std::vector of Triplet like this:

```
typedef Eigen::Triplet<double> T;
std::vector<T> tripletList;
tripletList.reserve(9);
tripletList.push_back(T(1,2,3));
tripletList.push_back(T(1,4,10));
// ...
SparseMatrix<double> mat(10,8);
mat.setFromTriplets(tripletList.begin(), tripletList.end());
```